# Mysql Error de incompatibilidad en windows comparado con linux

Tags: mysql, python, linux, windows

Lo que pasa es que hace algunas semanas estuve trabajando con un código que conectaría a una base de datos de mysql remota que cuenta con una versión vieja y es imposible cambiarla , pero mi problema no radica ahí, mi problema radica en que cuando pruebo mi código en Windows funciona perfectamente y la conexión a la base de datos se realiza perfectamente sin complicaciones, entonces el problema empieza cuando yo paso este código a producción a un sistema operativo en Linux ya que al momento de correr el programa me da un error que es BAD HANSHAKE he leído que este programa se debe a la incompatibilidad de versiones, pero estoy utilizando exactamente lo mismo en los 2 sistemas operativos , no se que tenga que instalar en Linux o si definitivamente no se puede, no se si a alguien le ha pasado pero me esta causando conflicto así como esta evitando el progreso de mi desarrollo de software......................................Estoy abierto a conectar cualquier duda referente a esto y cualquier sugerencia.

Comment: La pregunta es muy ambigua, ¿puedes proporcionar más información como logs, el traceback y las versiones?

Comment: Bueno para ejemplificarte mejor en mi entorno en linux estoy usando Django con un conector a base de datos Mysql llamado mysql.connector.django o mysql-connector-python el cual es el que conecta a mi base de datos, entonces cuando este programa se corre en windows Funciona a la perfeccion , entonces al pasarlo a Linux el mismo codigo sin ningun cmabio me tira el error "Bad Hanshake" el cual es un problema de la version de mysql a la que me quiero conectar, pero esto solo sucede cuando lo corro desde linux